# Best solution for a php cache that is updated multiple times per second

Tags: php, caching

I am creating a forum application in PHP. When the user goes to the first page of the forum, he gets the 25 topics that have last been updated.

I want to cache those 25 topics so that the database is never called to get the first page, this is basically how it would work:

- The cache is updated every time a user post on a topic / creates a topic
- This topic is added to the cache
- The oldest updated topic is removed from the cache

That way the cache always contains the last 25 updated topics and the server never makes a request to the database to get the first page of the forum.

I have already searched online to find solutions:

- APCu
- Redis
- Memcached

If the first page of my forum gets 100 get requests and 10 new posts per second, the cache will be updated 10 times per seconds, while being requested 100 times per second.

Which solution is the best for this kind of cache that is updated very often?

Comment: The question is why you want to avoid the DB call. You will have to go to the server which should be the majority of the time spent updating. In terms of simplicity of design you should just go to the server. However, if it was my site I might use web sockets to update in place as each topic was updated. The problem with that would be that the screen would jump around. I would then suggest you only update every couple of seconds, every 30 seconds, etc. I doubt if real-time updates are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The cache is updated every time a user post on a topic / creates a topic

I'd stop doing this.

Instead, set up an expiring cache (with a timeframe that suits your needs; every second? every 10 seconds? every minute? every five?) for the list you show on the home page. It's likely OK if someone doesn't see the new post from 500 milliseconds ago.

When that cache expires, it gets regenerated with the new list.

Alternatively, you could use Redis's [list functionality via LPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/lpush) to push new posts into a list, and remove the older ones with [LTRIM](https://redis.io/commands/ltrim). Your cache calls would access the list; the list itself is never *cleared*, just added to.